# Spring Data with pageable in nativequery

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this native query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM db_central.mensagem WHERE usuario_id = ?1",
            value = "SELECT m.id, m.data, u.nome as usuario, \n" +
            "ultima_visualizacao, \n" +
            "(SELECT max(resposta) FROM db_central.mensagem_destinatario md WHERE md.mensagem_id = m.id)as ultima_resposta, \n" +
            "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_central.mensagem_destinatario md WHERE md.mensagem_id = m.id) as destinatarios, \n" +
            "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db_central.mensagem_destinatario_resposta mdr JOIN db_central.mensagem_destinatario md ON md.id = mdr.mensagem_destinatario_id WHERE md.mensagem_id = m.id)  as responderam, \n" +
            "ARRAY(SELECT nome FROM db_central.mensagem_tipo_consulta mtc JOIN db_central.tipo_consulta tc ON tc.id = mtc.tipo_consulta_id WHERE mtc.mensagem_id = m.id ORDER BY natureza_cartorio_id) as tipos \n" +
            "FROM db_central.mensagem m \n" +
            "JOIN db_central.usuario u ON u.id = m.usuario_id WHERE m.usuario_id = ?1")
Page<MensagemEnviada> findByUsuarioId(Integer id, Pageable pageable);
```

And in my Controller I have

```
@GetMapping("/enviada/{id}")
public Page<MensagemEnviada> findEnviadas(@PathVariable  Integer id, @PageableDefault(sort = { "id"}, direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Pageable page){
        return mensagemService.findbyUsuario(id, page);
}
```

But when the spring generates the order by he put in alias `md.id` and the correct is `m.id`  Is it possible to configure this in Pageable?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your better? Don't Understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this updated alias prevent the query from working ?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya the spring generate my order by with a md.id instead m.id + "Order by md.id"  (the md table are a subtable in my select)